# Changes to admin requirements in Lion

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, packagemaker

Have the conditions which trigger a requirement for admin install changed in Lion?

Using packagemaker from the latest XCode (in Lion), a package that would previously install under the ownership of the current user (in Leopard/Snow Leopard) is now asking for an admin password and installing everything under the ownership of root.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's Lion or maybe changes to XCode but installing XCode and any XCode packages require admin. I haven't noticed any difference with other apps on Lion so I assumed it was XCode.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear, but the question is about packages *created* using the packagemaker in the latest XCode.